# I was caught cheating on my university GE exam

Tags: university, cheating

I got caught cheating on my university GE exam, and I am afraid suspension, I know I was wrong, should I just email prof to said I sorry and you can give me 0 in this exam or other advance to me that can help me avoid suspension?

Note: this is my first time, but I still afraid suspension, and my school is california state university.

Comment: Duplicate? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30539/i-was-caught-cheating-on-an-exam-how-can-i-minimize-the-damage

Comment: What is a GE exam?

Comment: @Buffy I’m guessing it’s an exam for a “General Education” course?

Answer (score 6):

First things first, what is GE? General Education (whatever that may be)? Second, do realize that this is more than just "wrong"; it is downright unethical. Copying in the workplace can get you into serious trouble and result in possible loss of your future work experiences/reputation. Also, don't tell the professor what to do. Don't even suggest the zero, let them handle it how they will. It was your fault, now it is up to them to make the decision.

On the lesser side of things, depending on the severity of cheating, you will definitely not be suspended. You may take an instant F in the class and have to re-take, but this is all should be outlined in their syllabus.

And finally, remove both your name and school from this posting. If a future employer sees this, they will not hire you, guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Every university has a set of rules, which defer from one to another. In Germany, where I finished my Bachelor and Master (without cheating ;)), it's the so called PO (Prüfungsordnung, in English known as exam regulations. In there you can find a clear description of the penalty that awaits you including if you have been caught multiple times, which you say you haven't been.

In the future avoid this sort of thing because it is unethical and is unfair to all your colleagues not to mention it puts you in a position where you can screw up your future.