# I don't know if i was caught cheating or not

Tags: cheating

So i take my test in a separate room by myself in the testing center and when i was taking my test one of the instructors nocked on my door. Know they do not check to make sure if you have your phone on you or not, so i brought my phone in the room with me. Well the teacher walks in and i hide my phone with my jacket on my lap and the teacher proceeds to say that i am not allowed to have a jacket in the room with me so i hide my phone between my legs and give her my jacket. Not thinking anything of it because i thought if she did see my phone than she would have taken my test away right then and there. 
So i finish the test and i go to hand it to the people and they are all talking when i get there but i don't know what they are talking about so i just pay no attention to it. As i am grabbing my jacket i hear one of the ladys say she is probably just gonna get a 0 on the test because when i walked in there she had her phone on her. Now they never said who they where talking about but i am scared because i did have my phone on me. When i was leaving they didn't seem to be mad at me or anything but i still can't help but think they where talking about me. 
So i guess what i am asking is if i did get caught with my phone would they have taken the test away or would they have let me finish and then emailed my teacher about it?

Comment: If they did, you will soon know.

Comment: So you are not allowed a phone in the exam but took it with you because “they don’t check”...

Comment: I think you know you were caught, the only question now is will you be formally accused and/or punished.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I hope you will learn your lesson and **not cheat again**. It is unfair to your fellow students and to your future employers. I strongly recommend to read the answers to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/30539/112007).

Now to your actual question: different universities in different countries have different policies on how to handle cheating. In some universities, students must always be allowed to finish the exam even if they are caught cheating, so that the grade is still valid if the accusation of cheating is appealed and does not stand.

You cannot know who the instructors were talking about: you will have to wait to see if they have caught you. I would say the odds are strongly against you: what are the chances that another student cheated in the same way as you did and was caught?