Academic Integrity accusation of generating a personal reflection with AI
Academic Integrity emailed that my submission from the last semester was more than 40% generated by artificial intelligence. They noted there are no grammatical errors in my submission and the writing style is bland and generic, and there is little reflection insight offered (which I usually did at that time because I had no clue when it came to personal reflection).
They offered the opportunity to review my submission and submit a written response addressing this allegation. What should I write in that response?
I actually do use AI sometimes when it gets really hard to paraphrase the text but in terms of personal reflection, I'm 100% sure that I did not use it. This is my first time experiencing this.

"I actually do use AI sometimes when it gets really hard to paraphrase the text but in terms of personal reflection, I'm 100% sure that I did not use it." You are not being very clear here. Did you or did you not use AI when writing this submission?

Several red flags here. My answer here may be relevant: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/173609/43544

The last sentence in your first paragraph is missing a punctuation mark at the end. Also, in your last sentence, you probably meant to write either "This is my first time experiencing this" or "This is the first time I experienced this."

"I actually do use AI sometimes when it gets really hard to paraphrase the text" - Instructors aren't asking you to paraphrase text just to avoid being accused of plagiarism as some sort of game. They're asking you not to copy directly because they want you to first understand the material in your own mind and then write about it. The understanding step is the important part, not the writing part. They want your writing as a measure of understanding and to motivate learning, not because they're in great need of dozens of essays on the same topic. Using AI for this cheats yourself.

Bryan's comment is to the point. Using technical tools to sidestep the "understanding step" is akin to using an e-scooter to sidestep a jogging exercise. Yes, you may be able to "accomplish" getting from point A to point B sooner, but you do not accomplish what the practice was meant for.

This is a difficult area, because both 'sides'/'parties' in the AI essay arms race tend to be in the wrong.
On your part:

Don't use LLMs to write your essays. No, really. There are many fascinating interactions an open-minded and creative person can have with an LLM on one's own time, but the...lowest-common-denominator use of "I don't know how to write this essay, I'm going to make [large brand-name chatbot] do it" is bad for everyone.
If your current writing feels bland and unreflective, well, that's true of a lot of people who aren't good at writing yet. "Yet" is doing some work here. While people vary in how good at writing they are, and how good at writing they could ever possibly be, it is still trainable. You can make your writing less bland and more reflective. You have to actually work at it, though.
Don't deny LLM use you've actually done. Not to us, not to your institution. This is dishonest and only prevents you from improving. It also burns the commons, such that real denials of false accusations aren't believed. This includes your own real denials!

On the institution's part:

"AI text detectors" do not work, full stop. Not at all. I have generated text directly from LLMs and put it through them and seen "0% AI" estimates, and I've seen text written decades before LLMs get near-certain readings. They work off loose patterns in the RLHF tendencies of...I think just ChatGPT alone, actually (GPT models that aren't the specific ChatGPT RLHF don't get high scores, ime). They cannot magickally detect AI. They are wrong, they do not work, and they are causing grief.
Having once been a 12-year-old who wrote a lot better than the average 12-year-old, I was accused by a teacher of having my parents write my essays. I feel for these kids now, who must have an even harder time of things. A lot of young people are good at writing in a practical sense, but haven't yet developed much metacognition or conceptual sophistication. If someone is looking for LLMs and refuses to believe young people can actually be good at writing, this is going to get falsely accused.
AI detectors are bad enough, but some institutions are apparently doing even worse things. I've heard of a professor who failed his whole class because he asked ChatGPT if it wrote their essays.

Be completely transparent in your response. This includes complete transparency about all past LLM use, no matter what implications you fear it will have for you. If you just "have used LLMs in the past", that doesn't say what -- did you do some light copyediting or have all your previous essays been 90% LLM-written? People will assume the worst, and have good reason to.
Do not use LLMs in the future to write your essays. You need to develop your metacognitive skills and conceptual sophistication -- this is the point of writing essays. If you do not develop these skills, your work will seem LLM-written forever.
Also, just to make this absolutely clear, write the response yourself. Do not have an LLM write it. It's admittedly very funny for everyone else when people send "As an AI language model, I can't tell you whether Name wrote his own essays", but it won't be very funny for you.

It seems like the existing answers didn't really answer your question, which is "What should I write in my rebuttal letter". Here is what I would write:

Demonstrate that you have an understanding in the topic. I'm unsure of the nature of your assignment, but let's say it is "Write an essay to prove that the earth is round". In this case, you can demonstrate that you have knowledge in the topic by listing out the history of flat earth vs round earth. This is probably a pretty bad example but without knowing what your assignment is, it is hard to give specific advice.

"Anti-AI" tools are no where near rigorous enough (at its current state) to definitively prove if someone has used AI (Generative AI, in particular). This is a fact that is backed by experiments (although I'm unsure if they are scientifically rigorous studies), although you can probably find multiple reputable articles on this topic. Using Anti-AI tools is akin to convicting someone based on a Polygraph test.

Specify that "no grammatical mistakes" could very well be due to other grammar checking tools (e.g Grammarly, unless Grammarly is also banned in your institution). Even then, having perfect grammar is not outside the realm of possibilities for someone who is articulate in English, or someone who is a really pedantic editor.


Overall, based on what you've written, seems like their argument is based on really shaky grounds. I'm honestly surprised that they even brought it up in the first place without basically any concrete evidence. I wouldn't be particularly worried if I were you, given that your institution has a strong ethical conducts policy and treats students fairly.


They're saying it is because there are no grammatical errors in my submission and the writing style is bland and generic

This is not a reason to suspect A.I. was used. People can just be subpar writers.

there is little reflection insight offered (which I usually did at that time because I had no clue when it came to personal reflection).

Well, it is true A.I. generally isn't good at reflecting/doing real analysis (even if it's very good at computation and certain forms of reasoning), so it's circumstantial, but again, people can just be poor writers.
Anyways, the fact that you used it at all for writing to me isn't very positive. I use GPT to translate MATLAB to Python all the time, with the understanding that it's totally on me to make sure the code works correctly and is optimized, and that's only because I don't speak MATLAB. For all the concepts though, you should be good enough to rephrase things nicely, and if you can't do it in your own words it suggests you don't understand it well enough. Plus, the issue is that there's no way we can publicly check the AI since presumably you don't keep all your GPT conversations laying around, making the overall document less transparent.
Anyways, be honest in your letter. Say the things you did use AI for and the parts you didn't use it for.

LLMs, which is presumably what OP means by AI here are not good at computation and don’t reason.
